# Is it possible to run Angular JS as a micro frontend in an Angular container micro frontend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, micro-frontend

I am doing research on how to move our app's front end monolith in to a micro frontend architecture. All the documentation I see around AngularJS and micro frontend usually talk about using the UpgradeModule that Angular provides and how to slowly take out Angular JS components while running the app in a Hybrid state.

This is not what I am trying to do. At this point we do not want to invest in migrating AngularJS components into Angular 8+. We are trying to have a micro frontend Architecture with an Angular 8 app as the container app (Handles navigation, auth, header, footer) and then have our AngularJS monolith as a web component  that lives inside the Angular 8 Container. Is this possible? And if it is how?

Comment: Can't you just render the appropriate element within the container app, as well as load the proper JavaScript for your Angular JS monolith which uses that mount? We do all of our micro frontends with React, and all we have to do is mount the `div` each frontend will use first, then mount the `script` element, pointing to the right JS file and the app mounts and loads as normal. I know AngularJS and Angular 8 are slightly different, but it seems like it would work somewhat similarly, right?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the single-spa library? It has helpers to integrate different frameworks like AngularJS. Look [here](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angularjs.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. use iframe. let's say you have to introduce a new feature to your application, then you create that feature in let's say react, deploy it somewhere and integrate it using iframe.